# How to make KDevelop use c style comments?

Tags: c++, c, comments, kdevelop

if I hit Ctrl-D KDevelop will comment out the line where my cursor sits, which is all good. What's not so good is the C++ style comments it chooses // I want it to use /**/. Is there a way to make KDevelop use C style comments?

The reasons I ask are:
1)
Our code guide line requires `/**/` 
2)
We import a lot of code and tweak it, we would have to mix `// /**/`, which is **ugly**. Since most C code out there use `/**/` that's a complete hassle. Emacs handles it nicely, and that's one of few hurdles blocking my switch to KDevelop.

Thanks!

Comment: `//` comments are generally considered to be safer given the problems of embedded C style comments. Is there a specific reason you prefer to use C style comments for temporarily commenting out lines?

Comment: `//` comments _are_ C-style comments since 1999.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the mode of the source to `ANSI C89` either manually `Editor->Tools->Mode->Sources->ANSI C89` or using a kate modeline `/* kate: syntax ANSI C89; */`